# Provide a full phase plane analysis for the model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, applications

Provide a full phase plane analysis for the model:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l} \epsilon\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-(x^3-Tx+b)\;,\;T>0\\\dfrac{db}{dt}=x-x_0\end{array} \right.$

So I'm trying to find critical points which turned out to be $(x,b)=(x_0,Tx_0-x_0^3)$ for me, next I found the Jacobian matrix (partial derivatives) and then eigenvalues: 
$\lambda_1=\frac12(T-3x_0^2-\sqrt{(T-3x_0^2)^2-4}\;)$ ; $\lambda_1=\frac12(T-3x_0^2+\sqrt{(T-3x_0^2)^2-4}\;)$

Now I'm not sure what to do next, how am I supposed to sketch a phase plane, while I have $2$ constants $T>0$ and $x_0$ (of course $\epsilon$ is also a small positive constant).

Also what does it mean to provide a full analysis of the phase plane? Is it just equilibrium points?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, usual stuff then: find where derivatives are positive or negative, sketch behaviour of solutions basing on that, apply common method for studying slow-fast systems, find when bifurcations happen (saddle-nodes, Andronov-Hopf), ....

Answer (score 1):

Some helping tips.

Regarding the equilibrium point, analyzing the eigenvalues we have that

$$
(T-3x_0^2)^2-4 \ge 0
$$

define real eigenvalues. This region is shown in the attached figure. In light blue where the eigenvectors are real positive and in light red where real negative . The white region is for complex eigenvalues.

[image]

Also is shown a stream plot for $x_0 = 0, T = 1, \epsilon = 0.2$ where can be observed a limit cycle around the origin.

[image]